Error "Unable to open file 'FIREDAC.CONSOLEUI.WAIT.OBJ'" al utilizar FireDAC en RAD Studio
Estoy desarrollando una API en C++ Builder de RAD Studio y estoy utilizando FireDAC para conectarme a una base de datos Oracle. Sin embargo, al compilar mi proyecto, recibo el siguiente error:
[ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'FIREDAC.CONSOLEUI.WAIT.OBJ'
He intentado las siguientes soluciones sin éxito:
Verifiqué que FireDAC esté correctamente instalado a través del instalador de RAD Studio,
Incluí explícitamente la unidad FireDAC.ConsoleUI.Wait en mi archivo de encabezado,
Configuré las rutas de búsqueda de archivos de encabezado y bibliotecas en las opciones del proyecto
Agradecería cualquier sugerencia o solución para resolver este problema. ¡Gracias!

No sé usar RAD Studio pero, ves el archivo FIREDAC.CONSOLEUI.WAIT.OBJ o con un nombre parecido por alguna parte? Tal vez sería útil si mostraras la configuración del proyecto
